# layout for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to understand how to use multiple layouts for different screens sizes properly.

I made two layouts: default and large for bt_control.xml

[image]

I own galaxy s8+ device so I made a virtual device with the same specs. The android studio recognize it as a "large" device as seen here:
[image]

But when I upload the app to my phone it display the default screen size layout (not the large).
what could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a complex one, but the short answer is that Android has different screen types and sizes, and therefore the determining factor on which resource gets used are:

- **Localization**
- **Pixel Density of your device**

Android looks at your Pixel density and determines which resource to use (if you specified any resources for large or small devices). But for this to work, you need to follow the localization and resource qualifier precedence. An example below:

[Which Resource Takes Precedence?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdtf9.png)

I recommend you take a look at [Localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) , [Alternative Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and [Different Screen Densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities). If your folder qualifiers are not setup correctly, Android will ignore these resources and use the default one. Your resource folder should look something like this:

```
res/
  drawable        <- default
  drawable-ldpi   <- Alternative resources for low to large pixel densities
  drawable-mdpi
  drawable-hdpi
  drawable-xhdpi
  drawable-xxhdpi
  drawable-xxxhdpi
  values-sw600dp/
  values-fr/     <- Values for french resources
  layout/        <- Layout default
  layout-land/   <- Alternative layout for landscape orientation
```

You can also Google these if the Android Developer Guide is too vague for you. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. But "large" means litle near to tablets, phones with a large density screen or so.

Instead of use "large". Use hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.

By using xhdpi or higher your phone will use them.